# Are "prototypical" and "prototypal" different?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I typed *prototypal inheritance* and got a wavy red underline conveying a alternative word for the same from Google. I am getting the same underline while typing this post. The suggestion is *prototypical*. Does *prototypal* exist as a word?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**prototypal inheritance**  is a technical term used in computer programming. The adjective indicates that the programming style is *based on protypes*.

> Prototype-based programming is a style of object-oriented programming
>   in which behaviour reuse (known as inheritance) is performed via a
>   process of cloning existing objects that serve as prototypes. This
>   model can also be known as prototypal, prototype-oriented, classless,
>   or instance-based programming. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming)

**prototypical inheritance**  would mean something different. It would indicate that the [mechanism of] inheritance  was itself a prototype.

**Answer**

Although in everyday English, 'prototypal' and 'prototypical' are synonyms with the former being the rarely used version, in a technical sphere it is permissible to *define* terms to mean what you want them to mean. The example you give is one such technical use.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to distinguish between **prototypical** and **prototypal** (without referencing a specific domain, such as object-oriented programming), I'd say that **prototypal** refers to a *manner or method* involving prototypes, and **prototypical** applies to  entities (and their behaviors) which are involved in a **prototypal** scenario.